# Ethers.js Deployment Issues with Ganache: Import Errors and Network Detection

Tags: ethers.js, ganache

I'm encountering deployment issues while using ethers.js with Ganache. Initially, I faced import statement errors with ethers v6 and downgraded to v5.7.2. However, I now encounter a network detection problem even though Ganache is running on `http://127.0.0.1:7545`. I've verified the RPC URL and made sure there are no firewall issues.

When I run `node deploy.js` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')
    at main (/home/kenny/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage-fcc/deploy.js:5:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kenny/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage-fcc/deploy.js:23:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I then checked ethers' docs and I saw the for version six, ethers is imported like so `import {ethers} from 'ethers'`. So, I downgraded to ethers@5.7.2 and ran `node deploy.js` again.
I then got this error:

```
Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/kenny/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/kenny/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (/home/kenny/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:609:54)
    at step (/home/kenny/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (/home/kenny/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (/home/kenny/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'could not detect network',
  code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
  event: 'noNetwork'
}
```

I have downloaded the ganache software and it's running.
This is my package.json file:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ethers": "5.7.2",
    "solc": "0.8.7-fixed"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "yarn solcjs --bin --abi --include-path node_modules/ --base-path . -o . SimpleStorage.sol"
  }
}
```

And this the tree of the directory I work in (node_modules ignored):

```
.
├── SimpleStorage.sol
├── SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi
├── SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin
├── deploy.js
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

I have the following setup in the main function...

```js
async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
  );
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0x304a46582cf53e833c8791c6dba539b9c5e673bcc0350ce5d6ed3ff8afcaee88",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf-8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf-8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  console.log(contract);
}
```

What's going on here?
I am running this on a WSL in VScode.

I have also tried logging the contractFactory to see if everything is fine. It's not undefined or anything.
It logs the following:

```
ContractFactory {
    bytecode: '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',
    interface: Interface {
      fragments: [Array],
      _abiCoder: [AbiCoder],
      functions: [Object],
      errors: {},
      events: {},
      structs: {},
      deploy: [ConstructorFragment],
      _isInterface: true
    },
    signer: Wallet {
      _isSigner: true,
      _signingKey: [Function (anonymous)],
      _mnemonic: [Function (anonymous)],
      address: '0xeA5D90e7276D1707C5948c3Af9Efd3d4ba530F6e',
      provider: [JsonRpcProvider]
    }
  }
```